# Fatal error: Uncaught Requests_Exception: cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 10009 milliseconds

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I try to run my third party API written in PHP but when I try to run it gives me an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Requests_Exception: cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 10009 milliseconds in D:\xampp\htdocs\ArchivLearn\Requests\library\Requests\Transport\cURL.php:428 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\ArchivLearn\Requests\library\Requests\Transport\cURL.php(179): Requests_Transport_cURL->process_response('', Array) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\ArchivLearn\Requests\library\Requests.php(381): Requests_Transport_cURL->request('http://api-core...', Array, Array, Array) #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\ArchivLearn\po_client.php(54): Requests::request('http://api-core...', Array, Array, 'POST') #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\ArchivLearn\po_client.php(31): POClient->request('post', '/apps/any/sessi...', Array) #4 D:\xampp\htdocs\ArchivLearn\pet_details.php(12): POClient->sign_in('ka83jf466', Array) #5 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\ArchivLearn\Requests\library\Requests\Transport\cURL.php on line 428

```
public function requestJSON($method, $path, $jsonString) {
    $timestamp  = $this->timestamp();
    $signature = $this->signature($path, $timestamp);
    $jsonString = str_replace('{accesskey}', $this->access_key, $jsonString);
    $jsonString = str_replace('{timestamp}', $timestamp, $jsonString);
    $jsonString = str_replace('{signature}', $signature, $jsonString);
    $jsonString = str_replace('{session}', $this->token, $jsonString);
    $headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => '*/*'];
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => $this->host.$path,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jsonString,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    if ($err) {
        error_log("requestJSON error".json_encode($err));
    }
    if ($response) {
        return json_decode($response);
    }
    return null;

}
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: It seems like the request takes longer than 10 seconds to complete and times out. You can always try and make the request timeout longer (using the `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` setting) or fix the API to be faster.

Comment: I post my code please check and explain how do I fix this issue

Comment: You're literally setting the timeout to 10 seconds: `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,`. If you need it to be longer, then set a longer timeout. Where did you get that code from in the first place since you don't know what it does?